How to opt out of analytics in the Autodesk Forge Viewer
The title says it all - How do I opt out of the analytics data collection by the Autodesk Forge Viewer? According to the official changelog, calling Autodesk.Viewing.Private.analytics.optOut(); should be enough, but it displays an error as shown in the screenshot.
We used to do this in our app as soon as the viewer is initialized and a model is shown but in the latest version (7.98.0) it seemed to stop working.
The error is reproducible using the "simple viewer" app from Autodesk: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/
Attached is a screenshot from the function call + error output using Chrome.
Any ideas?

Thank you for the heads up. Let me report this to the viewer team. In the meantime, consider disabling the the analytics by setting optOutTrackingByDefault to true in the initializer options:
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ optOutTrackingByDefault: true }, function () {
    // ...
});


Thank you, this one works! Unfortunately we can't do it though in our app since we use the encapsulated forge viewer from this project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-forge-viewer. might be another signal to move away from it finally since the project seems abandoned... Still, would be nice if the API call would be fixed. Thanks again for your help.
